# Qt/C++ Cast QGraphicsItem to custom QGraphicsItem without using dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, qt, object-oriented-analysis

I learned from OOAD class that dynamic_cast is a bad design 
but I don't know how can I do what I want without dynamic_cast in Qt
cause I can't just do polymorphism in QGraphicsItem.
Here is my code.

```
void Scene::changeName(){
    QList<QGraphicsItem*> selecitems = this->selectedItems();
    if(selectedItems().size()==1){
        Base* object = dynamic_cast<Base*>(selecitems[0]);
        bool isok;
        if(object){
            QString name = QInputDialog::getText( views().first()
                , tr("Change object name")
                , tr("Enter a name"),QLineEdit::Normal, "name", &isok);
            if(isok){
                object->setName(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change an item's name if it is a Base object and its the only one selected.

And I need the function "setName" in Base class.
Is there anyway to do what I want without using dynamic_cast?

In normal condition , I'll percolate up the function "SetName" in QGraphicsItem,
but it seems that I can't do this in Qt.

Comment: Just to check if I understand it correctly: `Base` is _derived_ from `QGraphicsItem` ?!

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt has its own casting function for `QGraphicsItem`: `qgraphicsitem_cast`. From the documentation:

> T qgraphicsitem_cast(QGraphicsItem * item)
>
> Returns the given item cast to type T if item is of type T; otherwise, 0 is returned.
>
> Note: To make this function work correctly with custom items, reimplement the type() function for each custom QGraphicsItem subclass.

On another note, bad design is bad, but how bad `dynamic_cast` is depends on how you use it :-)

Comment: So what is the difference between using qgraphicsitem_cast and dynamic_cast?

Comment: I think `qgraphicsitem_cast` use `dynamic_cast` under the hood, but I haven't checked it. Basically it's safer since `qgraphicsitem_cast` checks whether function `type()` returned id that equals `DerivedQGraphicsItem::Type` before casting.

Comment: @LebenAsa: If it used `dynamic_cast`, there wouldn't have been a need for `type()`. Qt predates decent C++ compilers and assumed RTTI was broken.

Comment: I thought `qgraphicsitem_cast` has bad design, or rather just don't have it at all. The only way it would be useful is that you can select items with this `type`, but it is not used anywhere, only for cast. Providing `constexpr Type` may sometimes be impossible, like if you have plugins, but I do not see why It cannot be declarated as static int, witch makes `qgraphicsitem_cast` not so completely useless, but you still need some kind of registry automation. `dynamic_cast` here is a good choice.

Comment: @MSalters @Arpegius: Yes. The problem with QGraphicsItem is the lack of signals and slots, thus encourages people to do manual _search and cast_. `type()` and `qgraphicsitem_cast` helped this somewhat, but its nowhere elegant.

Comment: @LebenAsa The lack of signals and slots is not a problem with QGraphicsItem. Use the right tool for the right job, which in this case would be [QGraphicsObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html)

Comment: @Arpegius: So we should use  `dynamic_cast` instead of `qgrahpicsitem_cast`? Or in my scenario both is just fine?

Comment: @Richard: Both is fine. The main point of my answer is you shouldn't be afraid to utilize run-time information. If you don't create hundreds of `Base`, using signals and slot with `QGraphicsObject` like @TheDarkKnight said is more appropriate.